# Does *ptr++ has a side effect on the next memory location?

Tags: c, pointers, operators

As far as I know, `*ptr++` should be evaluated to get the value in the original `ptr` address, and `ptr` gets updated to point to the next memory location. So the only thing that should be changing here is the address held by `ptr`.
However when I ran this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int x=5;
        int *ptr= &x;
        int val= *ptr++;
        printf("%i\n", val); 
        printf("%i", *ptr);
        return 0;
    }
```

I expected to get

```
5
//Some random value
```

But the output shows always

```
5
5
```

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: The number 5 qualifies as *"Some random value"*.

Comment: If you're really wondering why your input is generated twice, you can dig into assembly code and see why (it totally depends on the machine and compiler though).
In my case `gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18) 6.3.0 20170516`, if I give gcc -O1 or higher, the output became `5 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what I'm missing here?

The fact your program has undefined behavior. You may increment the pointer to point past an object (`x` in your example), but you may not dereference it afterwards. To do so is to venture beyond the promises a well-formed C program makes.

There's no reasoning about what `printf("%i", *ptr);` does, because it may do anything. Whatever guarantees the C standard placed on your program are forfeit the moment you do that access.

Beyond that, you also seem to be a victim of a logical fallacy. 5 is no less random here than 42, 106 or 0xf00ba7.

Comment: Yes, `5` might be indeed a random value, but what got my attention is whatever the value I assign to `x`, it gets printed twice. However, it's an Undefined behavior after all.

Answer (score 2):

All of your *knowledge* is correct, none of your *expectations* are.

To elaborate, in your case, the **problem** is

```
 printf("%i", *ptr);
```

you're trying to access (de-rererence) a memory which is *invalid* from the point of view of your program.

Remember, `ptr` itself got incresed, due to the post-increment operator use. Now it points past the address allocated for variable `x`. Then, you're trying to de-reference the address to fetch the value. This causes invalid memory access which in turn causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Once your program causes UB, the output (if any), cannot be validated or justified in any ways.